# Only Add element - not View/Read - Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have got a good script, which work perfect at Server Sharepoint - Farm Solution. It create Unique Permission group to whole site. Here is a script:

```
    $spweb=Get-SPWeb -Identity "http://sha..";
$spRoleDefinition = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition;
$spRoleDefinition.Name = "Submit only";
$spRoleDefinition.Description = "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them.";
$spRoleDefinition.BasePermissions = "AddListItems, ViewPages, ViewFormPages, Open";
$spweb.RoleDefinitions.Add($spRoleDefinition);
$spweb.Dispose();
```

How Could I done , run this script on Sharepoint Online ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function Create-PermissionLevel {
[cmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$ctx,
        [string[]]$permissions,
        [string]$defName,
        [string]$desc
    )
    $roleDefs = $ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions
    $ctx.Load($roleDefs)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
    $exists = $roleDefs | where {$_.Name -eq $defName}
    if (!$exists) {
        $roleDef = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.RoleDefinitionCreationInformation
        $basePerm = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.BasePermissions
        foreach($p in $permissions) {
            $basePerm.Set($p) 
        }
        $roleDef.Name = $defName
        $roleDef.Description = $desc
        $roleDef.BasePermissions = $basePerm    
        [void]$roleDefs.Add($roleDef)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Verbose "Created Permissions level $defName"
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "Role Definition already exists!"
    }
}
#Get your context
$pass = Read-Host -Prompt "Password:" -AsSecureString
$user = "you@wherever.microsoftonline.com"
$cred = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,$pass)
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext("https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/site")
$ctx.Credentials = $cred
#define perms
$permissions = "AddListItems", "ViewPages", "ViewFormPages", "Open"
#call function
Create-PermissionLevel -ctx $ctx -permissions $permissions -defName "Submit only" -desc "Can submit/add forms/files/items into library or list but cannot view/edit them."
```

Comment: Yes the function works fine. The error you are geting is due to your context being invalid. See https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29438.connect-sposervice-identity-client-runtime-library-idcrl-could-not-look-up-the-realm-information-for-a-federated-sign-in.aspx

Comment: Superb Solution :)