# Getting a Context using PowerShell and SharePoint Online Management Shell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

There are so many SharePoint code samples out there that it's really difficult to figure out what the current best way to do something is.  Forgive me as I may very well be mixing technologies.  Here's what I'm trying to figure out.

My environment:

- PowerShell v5.1 (Windows 10)
- Just downloaded SharePoint Online Management Shell yesterday, so it's the latest
- SharePoint Online with 2FA
- I am SharePoint Admin in the tenant

I'm seeing a lot of code samples for SharePoint Online that follow the same pattern.  Get a "Context", then do the work.  The 2 things I'm trying to do:

- I need to define an Add-only permission level like:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/212557
- I need to update the Created by field in all items in a list: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/11/update-created-by-modified-by-created-at-modified-at-values-using-powershell.html

But the way they get the context doesn't work for me because in my case we have 2FA.  So, code like this:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://XXXX.sharepoint.com/sites/XXXX/"
$Cred = Get-Credential
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
$rootWeb = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($rootWeb)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Returns error: "The sign-in name or password does not match one in the Microsoft account system."  Because it did not do 2FA.

So then I see other ways to "connect to SharePoint Online" with 2FA like this:

```
$orgName = "xxxx"
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOSite
```

I then try creating a context after I've successfully connected using Connect-SPOService with 2FA, like this:

```
$SiteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/"
$orgName = "lgrb"
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
$rootWeb = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($rootWeb)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

But this fails with "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

I just haven't been able to figure out how to marry the two.  I.e. how do I get a working "Context" after I've established the connection via Connect-SPOService.

Thanks in advance!

**Trying answer from SPM**

- Note: I was already able to successfully connect with Connect-SPOService before.  The problem happens after with the ClientContext doing ExecuteQuery
- I added the ClientContext code after the suggested code
- I used $cred that was set up in the suggested code to pass to the context for Credentials

  ```
  $orgName = "xxxx"
  $SiteUrl = "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxx/"
  $userName = "xxxx"
  $passWord = "xxxx"
  $encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
  $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord
  Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com

  $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
  $Ctx.Credentials = $cred
  $rootWeb = $Ctx.Web
  $Ctx.Load($rootWeb)
  $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  ```

However, the error is the same:

```
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."
At line:13 char:1
```

Comment: Can you please update your question with what you're trying to accomplish, i.e. you want to output xyz details about a file in a doc lib.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if it works, but try using [PnP PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) as following:

Connect to SPO:

```
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin
```

Define an Add-only permission level:

```
#Get Permission level to copy
$ContributeRole = Get-PnPRoleDefinition -Identity "Contribute"

#Create a custom Permission level
Add-PnPRoleDefinition -RoleName "Add-only" -Clone $ContributeRole -Exclude DeleteListItems, DeleteVersions -Description "Add-only"
```

Update the Created by field in all items in a list:

```
#Parameters
$ListName = "Branding"
$CreatedBy = "Salaudeen@crescent.com"

#Get all Items
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -ErrorAction Stop

#Update items properties
$ListItems | ForEach-Object {
    Set-PnPListItem -List $ListName -Identity $_.Id -Values @{"Author" = $CreatedBy;}
}
```

References:
[Connect to SharePoint Online using PowerShell with Multi-factor Authentication (MFA).](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/connect-sharepoint-online-powershell-using-mfa.html)

Comment: You are my hero!  This works.  Part of my problem is being new to SharePoint and simply not knowing which of the large number of SharePoint tool sets are "the new way to do things" and which are old and going away.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

For me, the below code worked with the MFA account:

```
$userName = "YourSPOUserName"
$passWord = "YourSPOPassword"
$encPassWord = convertto-securestring -String $passWord -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $userName, $encPassWord
 
Connect-SPOService -Url "https://globalsharepoint2020-admin.sharepoint.com"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. However it didn't help so far.  I'm editing my answer with the result.